# Scrolling background in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm drawing a background into kivy, and then wrap and place a transparent image on top of it. Each second I move the location of the transparent a little bit.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock

class ScrollApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.bkg = Background()
        self.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.bkg.scroll_texture, 1)
        return self.bkg


class Background(Widget):

    plx_2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # set as texture
        self.plx_2 = Image(source=r"assets\plx-2.2.png").texture
        self.plx_2.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.plx_2.uvsize = (1,-1)

    def scroll_texture(self, time_passed):
        # update uvpos
        x,y = self.plx_2.uvpos
        x = x - 0.05 % 1 # this magic number will change later
        self.plx_2.uvpos = (x, y)
        # redraw the image    
        texture = self.property('plx_2')
        texture.dispatch(self)


if __name__=='__main__':
    ScrollApp().run()
```

And the `.kv` file:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<Background>:    
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size : self.size
            pos : self.pos
            source: "assets\plx-1.png"
        Rectangle:
            size : self.size   
            texture: self.plx_2
```

The code works, but I feel very odd about the way I'm redrawing the texture with dispatching itself as an event. Is there a better way? Second, now if I were to add multiple transparent images on top, I would have to add a lot of code. Is there a a better way than just adding another `Rectangle` in the `.kv` file, adding another `ObjectProperty` in the `Background` class etc, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The only really odd thing I see is this:

```
x - 0.05 % 1
```

Modulation takes precedence over subtraction, and `0.05 % 1 == 0.05`, so the modulation has no effect. Is this what you intended?

Comment: I intended it to constrain x between 0 and 1, by only giving me the remainder. It should use brackets to first execute the `x-0.05`. Thanks for the catch!